# Google Docs won't underline misspelled words

Tags: google-workspace, google-docs-api

Out of nowhere, google docs stopped underlining misspelled words. I have tried every solution (clear cache, turning off extensions, changing web browsers, etc). A solution that was suggested was to open the tool drop-down and make sure the box for "underline" was checked off, but this box has mysteriously disappeared. Does anyone else have this issue and how do I fix it.